# GCC/G++ to use specific version of libc++

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, g++, c++20, libc++

I'm on Ubuntu 20 and want to try out some of the C++20 features, like `std::osyncstream` and by extension, the `<syncstream>` header. However, that is only available from `libc++-11` onwards, see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support.

I've installed `libc++-11-dev` but g++ still cannot find the `<syncstream>` header. I know clang has a -stdlib flag, can I somehow force `g++` to use the installed `libc++-11` version?

Comment: How are you compiling? Does it make a difference if you use `clang++`?

Comment: I'm running `g++-10` with flags `-g -Wall -std=c++20 -lpthread ...`. I'm afraid `clang++`'s libc++ does not support that feature

Comment: `libc++` _is_ LLVM:s (`clang++`'s) implementation of the standard library. `gcc`'s version is called `libstdc++`. Perhaps you downloaded the wrong library?

Comment: Sidenote: Use `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`.

Comment: Ah yes, I should have written `libstdc++`. If others are having this issue: I solved it by building (the experimental version) g++-11 locally.

Comment: Great! That soulds like something you could write up as an answer. It's ok to answer your own questions when you've figured something out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments of the question itself: The [experimental version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/g++-11-alpha-linux-gnu) of g++-11 can be built locally that solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to tell G++ to actually use that C++ language version. Use the `-std=c++__` compiler flag (e.g. `-std=c++20`)

Comment: I am doing that actually. I'm compiling with `g++-10` and flags `-g -Wall -std=c++20 -lpthread ...`